# Does Class.getDeclaredFields() return members in a consistent order?

Tags: java, reflection

The documentation describes the method as:

> The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any particular order

However I am not sure if this implies that the order will not be consistent each time the application invokes the routine.

I am looking for a way to pair a unique ID for each field that is found - but it also needs to be consistent with the next time the application is run, i.e continuously generate the same ID.

I am wanting to just iterate over each Field found and increment a counter per each element iterated. Then assign the ID of the particular element to whatever the counter is equal to, these 'ids' aren't consistent though if the Fields are not returned in a consistent order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order is not required to be stable across runs. However, the field's `hashCode()` value is defined to be stable (it's documented to always be `field.getDeclaringClass().getName().hashCode() ^ field.getName().hashCode()`), so you may be able to use that as your ID, with the understanding that the hash code is not guaranteed to be unique.

Alternatively, you may sort the results returned from `getDeclaredFields()` yourself, using whatever sorting criteria suits you.

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer. I am thinking I am going to sort the fields by name in a tree-map, and then apply the same algorithm I noted above to get the IDs (increment per every iteration)

Comment: @Jeremy Don't use a `TreeMap`. Just use `Arrays.sort`.

Answer (score 6):

> However I am not sure if this implies that the order will not be consistent each time the application invokes the routine.

It does not guarantee that it will be consistent over time.  But it might be consistent over time.

And the behavior might be different for different JVM versions or vendors.  And it might be affected by unexpected things ... like class unload / reload, or JIT recompilation.

In short, even if your scheme *appears* to work, it is liable to be fragile.  It is unwise to rely on undocumented behavior.

---

It also depends on what you mean by "over time".  If you mean "over time" within a single run of the application, then it is (IMO) more likely that order will be consistent than if you consider different runs of the application.

Finally, beware of using `hashCode()` to give you an ordering.  Hash codes can collide, and if you get a collision your ordering will be ambiguous.  The probability of a collision is small but not zero, and if your use-case is security related then it would not be difficult for someone with knowledge of the algorithm to manufacture a collision.